# Delete all all except one column in access 2007 using delete query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not familiar to SQL script in VBA Access script. Can you tell me what to do to delete data in all the column except one? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you say delete, if you mean replace column values with Null, you can do that with an `UPDATE` query.

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET
    ColumnA = Null,
    ColumnB = Null
```

Do that for all the columns whose data you wish to delete.

If that's not what you had in mind, please give us more detailed information to help us understand what you want.

Comment: That's what I intended. But I have around 40-50 columns and want to reset all the columns to null except one column in the table. I tried to use this query "delete * from table except table.column(column i don't want to delete)". But it did not work. Could you help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A `DELETE` statement deletes entire rows.  It won't let you discard values from some columns but leave the values in other columns intact.